# function to fill the top part of a table

Tags: c

I have a function that allows me to fill the top part of a table by a number like in this example with 1:

```
2 3 3 4
2 3 3 4 
2 3 4 5
3 4 2 4
```

becomes after applying the function :

```
2 1 1 1
2 3 1 1
2 3 4 1
3 4 2 4
```

This is my code (using an `if` test):

```
/* function */
void remplitPartieSup(int tab[N][N])
{ 
   int i,j;
   for (i=0;i<N;i++)
      {
        for (j=0;j<N;j++)
         {
           if (i<j)
             tab[i][j]=1;
         }
      }
}
```

**Question**

How can I achieve the same result without using an `if` test?

Comment: Using an `if` is exactly what you need to do in this case.  Why do you want to change that?

Comment: Change the bounds of the second `for` loop, incorporating `i`.

Comment: @dbush "need"? Perhaps the runtime requirements?

Comment: yes, I have to do it because that's what it's asked in the exercice

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
void remplitPartieSup(int tab[N][N])
{ 
   int i,j;
   for (i=0;i<N;i++)
      {
        for (j=i+1;j<N;j++)
         {
             tab[i][j]=1;
         }
      }
}
```

Comment: Can you just explain the logic behind this method ?

Comment: 'j' is always greater than 'i' by one or more, so 'if' is not needed.